# Java JsonObject array value to key

Tags: java, json

I'm new to java so this is a bit confusing

I want to get json formatted string

The result I want  is

```
{ "user": [ "name", "lamis" ] }
```

What I'm currently doing is this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();         
json.put("name", "Lamis");
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

And I'm getting this result

```
{"name":"Lamis"}
```

I tried this but it didnt work 
json.put("user", json.put("name", "Lamis"));

Comment: Nothing in your code mentions `user` so why do you expect it in the output?

Comment: I know , I dont know how to place it right.. but it gave weird results

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();         
json.put("user", new JSONArray(new Object[] { "name", "Lamis"} ));
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

**However** the "wrong" result you showed would be a more natural mapping of "there's a user with the *name* "lamis" than the "correct" result.

*Why* do you think the "correct" result is better?

Comment: Hmm I want this to add "age" too ..am I messing things up?

Comment: What's wrong with `{"name":"Lamis", "age":23}`? That's what a JSON object *should* look like and for that you're on the right path with your original code.

Comment: Thanks anyways, this is exactly
 what I wanted

Comment: Yes I'm realizing that now, but still it was good to know how to do it, because it took sometime of me

Answer (score 8):

Another way of doing it is to use a JSONArray for presenting a list

```
   JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
   arr.put("name");
   arr.put("lamis");

   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   json.put("user", arr);

   System.out.println(json);   //{ "user": [ "name", "lamis" ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are after is different than what you think you need;

You should have a separate 'User' object to hold all properties like name, age etc etc.
And then that object should have a method giving you the Json representation of the object...

You can check the code below;

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

public class User {
    String  name;
    Integer age;

    public User(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public JSONObject toJson() {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("name", name);
            json.put("age", age);
            return json;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User lamis = new User("lamis", 23);
        System.out.println(lamis.toJson());
    }
}
```