# Android JSONObject : add Array to the put method

Tags: java, android, json

```
// JSON object to hold the information, which is sent to the server
JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
jsonObjSend.put("action", "myAction");
jsonObjSend.put("type", tipo);
```

For now is everything ok but if I want to add

```
jsonObjSend.put("elementi", arrayOfElements);
```

where arrayOf Elements must be an array of strings. How can I do?

/****** EDIT

EXAMPLE OF WHAT I NEED

```
{
  "action": "myAction",
  "type": "elementi",
  "elementi": [
    "3287498357",
    "23472857"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

After seeing the example I understood that you are trying to do something similar as asked in [Java JsonObject array value to key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704144/java-jsonobject-array-value-to-key)

```
jsonObjSend.put("elementi", new JSONArray(new Object[] { "value1", "value2", "value3"} ));
```

To simplify:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put("value1");
arr.put("value2");
//...
jsonObjSend.put("elementi", arr);
```

Comment: I think that isn't the solution for my problem. I add an example of what I need. Take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
jsonBody.put("action", "myAction"); //action is your string
jsonBody.put("type", "elementi");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
JSONObject elementi= new JSONObject();
itemList.put("id", id);
itemList.put("name", name);
arr.put(elementi);
jsonBody.put("elementi", arr);
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain why your code would work.

Comment: It will work if you want to create an array inside the object and yes it works for me!

Comment: What is itemList??

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly add the array as a JSONArray object:

```
// JSON object to hold the information, which is sent to the server
JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
jsonObjSend.put("action", "myAction");
jsonObjSend.put("type", tipo);
jsonObjSend.put("elementi", JSONArray(arrayOfElements));
```