# How to send json array as post request in volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am using volley for json parsing. I want to send some data using POST to server side. I am trying to send .Now can any one tell me that how can i send filter array to server?

Following is my snippet code. i tried also `Hashmap` and `Jsonobject`. but getting this error.

Error :

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  at Data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Format

```
{
    "typeName": "MANUFACTURER",
    "typeId": 22,
    "cityId": 308,
    "sortBy": "productname",
    "sortOrder": "desc",
    "filter":[
                {
                    "filterId":101,
                    "typeName":"CAT_ID",

                     "filterId":102,
                    "typeName":"CAT_ID"
                }
             ]
}
```

For Code Check pastie

https://pastebin.com/u5qD8e2j

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272442/7073808)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are having a problem in calling the API then this will help you.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest jobReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jObject,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });

queue.add(jobReq);
```

where jObject is the JSON data you want to send to the server.

Implementation will be similar for JSONArray. Instead of JsonObjectRequest 
 use JsonArrayRequest and send jArray instead of jObject.

For creating json array just do a little tweak

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();

for(int i=0;i<filter_items.size();i++){
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("filterId",filter_items.get(i));
        obj.put("typeName","CAT_ID");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    array.put(obj);
}
```

And finally add json array as below

```
jsonParams.put("filter",array);
```

In your case you are converting Json array to string

Comment: hey kunu  neither map nor jsonobject is working properly

Comment: _What do you mean by not working properly?_ Because if you implement correctly it's gonna work.Show your implementation and error.

Comment: Use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to check your response

Comment: bro did you check error? and response is false..cuz of error

Comment: And though your request format is correct it depends on what your server expects to receive. That's why I am asking you to check in Postman then cross check with your code.

Comment: Do you want send a Json array or a json object?

Comment: Same issue bro..no change..and in my log i am getting this..for request

{"typeName":"MANUFACTURER","typeId":"22","cityId":"308","sortBy":"productname","sortOrder":"desc","filter":"[{\"filterId\":\"128\",\"typeName\":\"CAT_ID\"}]"}

Comment: Check again my answer

Comment: Do not convert json array to string just add it in Json object as it is.

Comment: incredible answer bro..accepted ..for bounty its not allowing for 24 hours

Comment: Gives me `wrong 2nd type argument, required String found JSONArray error`. `When I convert jsonArray.toString()` it gives me `cast to Array failed error`

Comment: @BugsBuggy Can you post your question and redirection link here?

Answer (score 7):

I used below code to post JSONArray to volley. You have to use JsonArrayRequest and pass the JSON Array directly without adding it to any JSONObject.
Also keep in mind to Override the "parseNetworkResponse" method to convert the response to JSONArray again as The ResponseListner for JsonArrayRequest expects a type of JSONArray

```
    String URL = "www.myposturl.com/data";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Create json array for filter
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    //Create json objects for two filter Ids
    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonParam1 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        //Add string params
        jsonParam.put("NAME", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        jsonParam.put("USERNAME", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        jsonParam.put("PASSWORD", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        jsonParam1.put("NAME", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        jsonParam1.put("USERNAME", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        jsonParam1.put("PASSWORD", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    array.put(jsonParam);
    array.put(jsonParam1);
    JsonArrayRequest request_json = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, array,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Get Final response
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", volleyError.getMessage());

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // Add headers
            return headers;
        }
        //Important part to convert response to JSON Array Again
        @Override
        protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString;
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            if (response != null) {

                try {
                    responseString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    (array).put(obj);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            //return array;
            return Response.success(array, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };
    queue.add(request_json);
```

Comment: You saved my day with this great tip to override parseNetworkResponse!

Comment: My long search for the most appropriate answer ended here. I appreciate this man. Kudos!

Answer (score 3):

```
{
"typeName": "MANUFACTURER",
"typeId": 22,
"cityId": 308,
"sortBy": "productname",
"sortOrder": "desc",
"filter":[
            {
                "filterId":101,
                "typeName":"CAT_ID",
             }
             {
                 "filterId":102,
                "typeName":"CAT_ID"
            }
         ]
}


JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
object.put("typeName","");
object.put("typeId","");
object.put("cityId","");
object.put("sortBy","");
object.put("sortOrder","");
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("filterId","");
obj.put("typeName","");
array.put(obj);
object.put("filter",obj.toString());
```

pass JSONObject to make request. use this https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: but there are two filterId i need to add..how will i add it?

Comment: You can create multiple JSONObject and add them to JSONArray.

Comment: its not possible i guess.

Comment: oh yes i created as you said..but now strange issue i am getting..if i add cityId i am not getting response.. but if i remove cityId i am getting response..webservice works fine in postman and other tools..so there is not any issue in webservice..can you help?

Comment: can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you.

```
    //Create Main jSon object
    JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();

    try {
        //Add string params
        jsonParams.put("typeName", "MANUFACTURER");
        jsonParams.put("typeId", "22");
        jsonParams.put("cityId", "308");
        jsonParams.put("sortBy", "productname");
        jsonParams.put("sortOrder", "desc");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Create json array for filter
    JSONArray array=new JSONArray();

    //Create json objects for two filter Ids
    JSONObject jsonParam1 =new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonParam2 =new JSONObject();

    try {

        jsonParam1.put("filterId","101");
        jsonParam1.put("typeName","CAT_ID");

        jsonParam2.put("filterId","102");
        jsonParam2.put("typeName","CAT_ID");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Add the filter Id object to array
    array.put(jsonParam1);
    array.put(jsonParam2);

    //Add array to main json object
    try {
        jsonParams.put("filter",array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For more information on how to create json object check this link

[Android JSONObject : add Array to the put method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563267/android-jsonobject-add-array-to-the-put-method)

**EDIT**:

In case of more data it is better to use Gson convertor

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html

Also for creating pojo classes use this

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: nope..there could be n numbers of filterID and typename.. it could be 1 or 5 or 2 ..cant assume it..its dynamic

Comment: edited the answer..check now..that is the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

Hi Volley does not support JsonArray request better use some other libraries...

Comment: Volley being open-source library allows you to customize it source code to introduce new constructors and overrides to methods. So replacing Volley just for such enhanced support is not Wise.

Answer (score 0):

Following three steps should make it work for old Volley libraries lacking this suport.

1. Prepare payload and post:

   ```
                       JSONArray payloadItems = new JSONArray();

                 JSONObject payloadItem1=new JSONObject();
                //set properties on item1
                payloadItem1.put('prop1',"val11");

                 payloadItems.put(payloadItem1);

                JSONObject payloadItem2=new JSONObject();
                //set properties on item1
                payloadItem2.put('prop1',"val12");

                payloadItems.put(payloadItem1);


                JsonArrayRequest request;

                request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,payloadItems, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                       //your logic to handle response
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       //your logic to handle error
                   }
               }) {

                   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                       Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                       /* This is very important to pass along */
                       params.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                       //other headers if any
                       return params;
                   }

                    };




                   request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 2, 2));
                   VolleyHelper.init(this);
                   VolleyHelper.getRequestQueue().add(request);
   ```
2. [If Needed] Add this constructor in Class- JsonArrayRequest in Volley package if not already there

   ```
     public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonArray, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
       super(method, url, (jsonArray == null) ? null : jsonArray.toString(),
               listener, errorListener);
   ```

   }
3. [If Needed] Override this method if not yet implemented to support JSONArray response from server.

   ```
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String responseString;
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        if (response != null) {

            try {
                responseString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                (array).put(obj);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        //return array;
        return Response.success(array, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
   ```